# Sync local and server time

Tags: time, synchronization, macrabbit-espresso

I am working with espresso for Mac, and I've found that I may have a problem with publishing tools.

My server is located at the USA, but I, and my computer, are located in Spain. So when I modify a file in my computer, and then one of my partners edits it again in the USA, if I do a sync, I erase his file with mine ... even being mine older.

I think that this is happening because my TIMESTAMP is in GMT+1, while server and partners time is GMT-8 (California), so their file will only be newer than mine if they touch it 9 hours later.

How can I fix that??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

In Espresso 1, go to the server's preferences and expand advanced settings (could be named something different, I'm working from memory). There should be a button to detect the time difference between your computer and the server. Use that and you should be good to go. I think Espresso 2 does this automatically now.

If you continue to have issues, send a message to support@rhinointernet.com. They like to take care of FTP issues over email.